# How to use sync on a 3 model relationship? - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 models:

`Match` `Team` `Player`

And i want to create a table with the following structure:

```
id | match_id | team_id | player_id
```

So that i can associate the 3 models i refered.

I created a 4th model `MatchPlayers` for the table i referred and I can use the 'search' functions without a problem. Like this:

```
$match->matchPlayers()->first()->team()->get()
```

And it returns the excpected result, but I cant do a

```
$match->matchPlayers()->sync([])
```

So, how should i solve this? Is my relationship wrong or the sync method isnt allowed on a 3 model relationship and I shoud use other method?

Thanks in advance

---

Edit:

```
Match.php

public function teamPlayers(){
    return $this->hasMany('\Modules\Matchs\Entities\MatchPlayer');
}

Team.php

public function matchTeamPlayers(){
    return $this->hasMany('\Modules\Matchs\Entities\MatchPlayer');
}

Player.php

public function matchTeamPlayers(){
    return $this->hasMany('\Modules\Matchs\Entities\MatchPlayer');
}

MatchPlayer.php

public function player(){
    return $this->belongsTo('\Modules\Players\Entities\Player');
}

public function match(){
    return $this->belongsTo('\Modules\Matchs\Entities\Match');
}

public function team(){
    return $this->belongsTo('\Modules\Teams\Entities\Team');
}
```

Comment: `sync()` is not available on `HasMany` relationships. Maybe you explain exactly what your goal is, then we can suggest how to do it. (Btw, I consider your current relationship design correct. So this is not the issue.)

Comment: My objective is to be able to send match_id, team_id and an array of player (player_id) and insert those records. And, also, if there is any combination of match_id, team_id with a player_id that is not on the array it deletes that record. I am not sure if this method already exists? (it is similar to the sync, on many-to-many relationship)

Comment: This is no built-in, but I use something similar in one of my applications as well. Please refer to my answer below. Of course most of the methods can be swapped by an alternative implementation, but this is the most concise one I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you've followed the Laravel documentation on Pivot tables and Many-Many relationships [found here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), and it's still not working, you might have more luck with "Attach". For example;

```
$matchPlayer = MatchPlayer::create([...]);

$match->matchPlayers()->attach($matchPlayer)
```

A good example of sync vs attach can be found [here](http://findnerd.com/list/view/Laravel-Eloquent---Attach-vs-Sync/12336/%20here)

Comment: Both sync and attach return as "does not exist".

I added my model structure/relations on the main topic, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Using a fourth model for this kind of relationship makes sense, as it gives you a navigation property for the third relation on your pivot table. This way you can form more complex queries this way.

For your particular problem, syncing based on `match_id` and `team_id`, I would simply do something like this:

```
$matchId = 123;
$teamId = 234;
$rows = [
    ['match_id' => $matchId, 'team_id' => $teamId, 'player_id' => 345],
    ['match_id' => $matchId, 'team_id' => $teamId, 'player_id' => 346],
    ['match_id' => $matchId, 'team_id' => $teamId, 'player_id' => 347],
];

// remove all previously stored connections
MatchPlayer::where('match_id', $matchId)
    ->where('team_id', $teamId)
    ->delete();

// insert the news ones
// (you could also use MatchPlayer::create() per item or 
// $matchPlayer->save(), it doesn't matter)
MatchPlayer::insert($rows);
```

---

If this operation occurs very frequently, you will potentially burn through a lot of `id` values of the pivot table. In this case you could also perform a more efficient sync, which is slightly more complex:

```
$matchId = 123;
$teamId = 234;
$rows = [
    ['match_id' => $matchId, 'team_id' => $teamId, 'player_id' => 345],
    ['match_id' => $matchId, 'team_id' => $teamId, 'player_id' => 346],
    ['match_id' => $matchId, 'team_id' => $teamId, 'player_id' => 347],
];

// delete all players that are not among the new data anymore
MatchPlayer::where('match_id', $matchId)
    ->where('team_id', $teamId)
    ->whereNotIn('player_id', array_pluck($rows, 'player_id'))
    ->delete();

// remove rows from new data that already exist
$exist = MatchPlayer::where('match_id', $matchId)
    ->where('team_id', $teamId)
    ->pluck('player_id')
    ->toArray();
$rows = array_filter($rows, function ($value, $key) use ($exist) {
    return ! in_array($value['player_id'], $exist);
});

// then we store the remaining data
MatchPlayer::insert($rows);
```